# Do I have to follow OAuth workflow (request token -> access token -> API call) everytime?

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Ok so I'm new to OAuth and I'm creating an app that integrates with Twitter.

I'm using Twitter4j and following their instructions. No problems there.

- I can ask the user to authorize my app
- I exchange a Request Token for an Access Token
- Once the user athorizes the app I serialize the object
- Here's how the serialization occurs

  ```
  FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(accessToken);
  oos.close();
  ```

So when it's time to use the Access Token again, I simply desiralize the object and then assign to a new Twitter object and invoke a status update, as below:

```
AccessToken twitterToken = objectDeserialization();
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(twitterApiKey, twitterApiSecret);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(twitterToken);
twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus("This is sparta! :)");
```

The problem is that I'm getting a 401.

**Everywhere I read I'm convinced that I'm not supposed to go through the whole token exchange thing again. Am I wrong?**

**Maybe I should simply store the Access Token and the Access Token Secret and create a new object from scratch instead of deserializing an old one?**

Appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem and the solution is: save only the Token and Token Secret and then create a new object.

```
AccessToken twitterToken = objectDeserialization();
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(twitterApiKey, twitterApiSecret);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(twitterToken.getToken(), twitterToken.getTokenSecret()));
twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus("This is sparta! :)");
```